# Automated way to create multiple kubernetes Job manifests

Tags: kubernetes, automation, manifest, kustomize, yq

Cron template

```
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: some-example
  namespace: some-example
spec:
  schedule: "* 12 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: some-example
            image: gcr.io/some-example/some-example
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            env:
             - name: REPO_URL
               value: https://example.com/12/some-example
```

I need to create multiple Job files with different URLs of `REPO_URL` over 100s save in a file. I am looking for a solution where I can set Job template and get the required key:value from another file.

so far I've tried https://kustomize.io/, https://ballerina.io/, and https://github.com/mikefarah/yq. But I am not able to find a great example to fit the scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be pretty trivial with `yq` and a shell script. Assuming
your template is in `cronjob.yml`, we can write something like this:

```
let count=0
while read url; do
  yq -y '
    .metadata.name = "some-example-'"$count"'"|
    .spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[0].value = "'"$url"'"
  ' cronjob.yml
  echo '---'
  let count++
done < list_of_urls.txt | kubectl apply -f-
```

E.g., if my `list_of_urls.txt` contains:

```
https://google.com
https://stackoverflow.com
```

The above script will produce:

```
[...]
metadata:
  name: some-example-0
  namespace: some-example
spec:
  [...]
              env:
                - name: REPO_URL
                  value: https://google.com
---
[...]
metadata:
  name: some-example-1
  namespace: some-example
spec:
  [...]
              env:
                - name: REPO_URL
                  value: https://stackoverflow.com
```

You can drop the `| kubectl apply -f-` if you just want to see the
output instead of actually creating resources.

---

Or for more structured approach, we could use Ansible's [k8s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html)
module:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - k8s:
        state: present
        definition:
          apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
          kind: CronJob
          metadata:
            name: "some-example-{{ count }}"
            namespace: some-example
          spec:
            schedule: "* 12 * * *"
            jobTemplate:
              spec:
                template:
                  spec:
                    containers:
                    - name: some-example
                      image: gcr.io/some-example/some-example
                      imagePullPolicy: Always
                      env:
                       - name: REPO_URL
                         value: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - https://google.com
        - https://stackoverflow.com
      loop_control:
        index_var: count
```

Assuming that the above is stored in `playbook.yml`, running this with
`ansible-playbook playbook.yml` would create the same resources as the
earlier shell script.

Comment: ansible will be another tool in a bucket not feasible, YQ / bash seems promising, thanks for your time on this.